# Filebeat, Kafka - topic name by %{[type]} or constant value?

Tags: filebeat

I have filebeat, which outputs to kafka.
Depending on `type` of document, I need to send logs to different topics.

In pseudo code:

```
if(type == type1)
topic = 'special.type1.topic'
...
else
topic = '%{[type]}'
```

I found that this is possible:

```
topics:
      - topic: 'special.type1.topic'
        when: 
          equals:
            %{[type]}: type1
```

But if `type` is none of the tested, I want to use default topic name, as seen in pseudo by `else` statement. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provide a default topic field for all untested files. When none of the rules match in "topics" then topic field is used.

In this case you will not need any rule for else in "topics". There your configuration will look something like this:

```
   topic: untested-files
   topics:
      - topic: 'special.type1.topic'
        when: 
          equals:
            %{[type]}: type1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I solved it by standardizing document_type and now I am using topic definition as:  topic = '%{[proj]}.%{[app]}.%{[type]}'. But I will mark your answer as Solved because of people looking for this solution. I have not tested your solution.